# %s - что за элемент синтаксиса?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Изучаю Django по [djbook.ru](https://djbook.ru/).

Вот фрагмент кода, в котором фигурирует этот `%s`. Что-то не пойму.

Это вводная часть, но я полагаю, разъяснён должен быть каждый элемент.

```
def results(request, question_id):
    response = "You're looking at the results of question %s."
    return HttpResponse (response % question_id)

def vote(request, question_id):
    response = "You're vouting at question %s."
    return HttpResponse (response % question_id)
```

Comment: Изучите сначала Python.

Comment: Это подстановка значения в `%s` у строки, попробуйте `print(response % question_id)`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ :)

Comment: Segey Gornostaev, пришлось осваивать Python и Django параллельно, кавалерийским наскоком.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Постановочный оператор, используется не только в Питоне.

`%s` заменяется на указанную подстроку

В вашем случае по видимому заменяется на `question_id`.

см. https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/formatirovanie-strok-operator.html

Comment: Спасибо за ответ :)

Answer (score 1):

Подставление значения в место с указанием типа. В данном случае: s - string

Answer (score 1):

Это "старый", унаследованный от языка Си, синтаксис форматирования строки. Вместо `%s` подставится значение переменной `question_id`.

Через метод `.format` строки будет выглядеть так:

```
def results(request, question_id):
    response = "You're looking at the results of question {}."
    # Вместо фигурных скобок в строке response подставится значение question_id:
    return HttpResponse (response.format(question_id))
```

Или через новый синтаксис (f-строки) (начиная с Python 3.6):

```
def results(request, question_id):
    # Вместо имени переменной в фигурных скобках подставится значение переменной:
    return HttpResponse (f"You're looking at the results of question {question_id}.")
```